# This server could not prove that it is localhost; its security certificate is from example.com

Tags: security, ssl, certificate

I have an admin web ui running on a non-public facing server that I would like to members of my team to access from Chrome without getting SSL warnings.

The http port is bound to `locahost:8080` on the server and until now I've just used local port forwarding (`ssh -L 8080:localhost:8080 aaron@dev.example.com`).

As a control test I bound the port to a public interface, created a self-signed cert and imported this manually into Chrome before trusting it (to get rid of the CA not trusted message). Using Chrome to access the public interface results in a closed padlock - so all is secure.

If I now set up the local port forwarding and replace `https://example.com:8080` with `ttps://localhost:8080` I get an error from Chrome:

> This server could not prove that it is `localhost`; its security certificate is from `example.com`.

I'm going to have a few different servers whose admin UIs I need to expose. For each, my plan was to use a cert based on the FQDN of the host but as the above doesn't work I'm not sure this will.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This resource may help: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/.  Also do a proxy instead of a redirect, so that the browser keeps seeing the FQDN instead of the localhost name.